# Fitness trainer put me on a muscle building program even though I have a 38 inch waist line

Tags: muscle, bodybuilding, muscle-gain, body-fat

I am a 5'6" 31M and I weigh 165 lbs. My fitness trainer put me on a muscle building program even though I have 38 inch waist line. The Evolt machine said I have 30% body fat and I read that for such people, the best bet is to focus on cutting first while keeping protein intake high and lifting heavy 3-4 times per week. Muscle building requires going on a bulk and I am not sure if at 30% BF I should be doing that.

I told my trainer this and he told me that when I put on muscle, my metabolic rate will increase and it will raise my caloric expenditure even when I am not actively training. Hence, he said muscle building is a suitable option for me in my current state.

Is his claim correct? Please let me know what you think.

Comment: Does the muscle building program include a diet plan or is it just training?

Comment: @DeeV They told me how many grams of protein, carbs and fats I should eat. They also listed supplements. Is this what you mean by diet plan? On top of that, they train me 2 days a week for an hour each.

Comment: Yes, macronutrient prescriptions (grams of protein, carbs, and fat) are a diet plan.

Comment: @DavidScarlett ok

Answer (score 6):

> muscle building program

Training programs for building muscle are the same regardless of whether or not you are cutting. Cutting training may need to deal with recovery a bit more, but overall the basic principles are the same.

> Muscle building requires going on a bulk

Not necessarily. Muscle building requires stimulus, energy and protein. Eating in a caloric surplus makes it easier to get the last two. Being overweight can ensure the energy part.

There are four types of people who can gain muscle while eating on a deficit:

1. Those who are new to lifting.
2. Those who are overweight.
3. Those who are on PEDs.
4. Those who are some combination of 1-3.

> The body scan machine said I have 30% body fat and I read that for such people, the best bet is to focus on cutting first

I would agree with this statement. However there are other things to consider like how easy it is to adhere to the plan. Maintenance and slight deficits are easier to follow. Especially if you're building and learning new habits like calorie/macro counting and training.

> he told me that when I put on muscle, my metabolic rate will increase and it will raise my caloric expenditure even when I am not actively training

That's technically true, but it's not very much. It's about on average [10 calories per LB](https://www.strongerbyscience.com/calories-muscle-burn/) or 5 calories per KG. So let's say you had a great year and managed to add a whopping 20 lbs (10KG) of lean muscle, your TDEE would have increased 200 calories a day.

> Hence, he said muscle building is a suitable option for me in my current state.

I believe this statement is true. Not just for weight loss, but for overall health, lifestyle, and longevity.

---

I personally in that position would start at a maintenance plan or maybe even slightly under (around 250 calories).

Although I can't speak for your trainer. That may be what (s)he has planned but is starting with a starting point just to test and assess how your body reacts. Hopefully, they will adjust accordingly to meet your goals.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate response. `Not necessarily. Muscle building requires stimulus, energy and protein.` The Evolt machine I was measured on stated that for muscle gain, I should eat around 200 g of protein. It seems to indicate I should be in a caloric surplus. My concern is that I am already overweight and eating in a surplus will add more fat to my body. I don't think I can afford that at 30% body fat, no?

Comment: It's worth noting that assuming you're a man and not asian, you're considered to be at increased risk (of excess adiposity related diseases) if your waist circumference is above 37", and at greatly increased risk if it's above 40". So at 38", you're only just into the potential problem zone, and certainly not dangerously overweight. I disagree with the trainer's strategy and would be much more inclined to start without a deliberate dietary intervention and see how your body changes first, but I wouldn't regard a slight caloric surplus as grossly negligent advice.

Comment: @DavidScarlett I am a man and of Indian (South Asian) ethnicity

Comment: @a_sid Ah, in that case the recommendation is to keep your waist circumference below 35.4 inches, so losing weight would probably be a good idea, but you may actually find that with your strength training, your waist circumference goes down even if you're losing weight!

Comment: @a_sid 200g of protein is grossly excessive for someone of your size. 120g would be more than sufficient.

Comment: I would've recommended more like ~140g, but still 200g is definitely too much. I'm 6'2 and ~200lb/91kg and I only eat 180g protein, and still, that at the top end of the scale, because I train often and with high intensity.

Comment: @Ethan yeah, 120g is the bottom end of that classic 1.6-2.2 g/kg recommendation. Newer research is, in my opinion, taking that bottom end from 1.6 to even as low as 1.3 g/kg without making compromises in hypertrophy and strength in cohorts from the general population, though I’d agree, someone trying to optimize or train for a competition could benefit from being in that 1.6-2.2 range.

Comment: @a_sid: `The Evolt machine I was measured on stated that for muscle gain, I should eat around 200 g of protein. It seems to indicate I should be in a caloric surplus.`-> This sounds like this machine is just spitting out generic advice without taking in to account anything. As others have said 200g for your size is a really high amount. I'm not even sure where it came up with that number because it goes against everything I've seen in research or even bro-science.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov - the main reason I choose to eat a slight protein surplus is that I like to be optimal. I try to eat enough but I'm not overly militant when it comes to my diet so that extra 20g of protein provides a buffer if I'm just 100-200cal shy of my target.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the helpful advice

Comment: @DavidScarlett `you may actually find that with your strength training, your waist circumference goes down even if you're losing weight! ` Isn't the reduction of waist circumference a natural consequence of losing weight?

Comment: @DavidScarlett `I disagree with the trainer's strategy and would be much more inclined to start without a deliberate dietary intervention and see how your body changes first,` Are you saying a more suitable strategy for me is to just exercise without changing my diet first?

Comment: @a_sid I'm saying that's how I would approach it, because tracking everything you eat is a huge amount of work that most people will fail at, and it may not be necessary as beginning an exercise program can change your appetite and cause you to eat less anyway. So I would always see what happens first with just an exercise intervention. But I'm not saying that's the only suitable strategy or that any other approach is wrong.

Comment: @a_sid Sorry, I meant to say that with strength training your waist circumference may go down even when you are gaining weight. If you are losing weight then it should definitely go down!

Comment: @DavidScarlett `Sorry, I meant to say that with strength training your waist circumference may go down even when you are gaining weight.` Oh I see. How does that happen? Is it due to the increased metabolic rate or something?

Comment: @a_sid muscles are denser than fat, so you increase in weight as you gain muscle and decrease in size as you lose fat.

Comment: @Luciano oh ok. that makes sense